# How to batch create PostgreSQL databases?

Tags: postgresql

How can one batch create many PostgreSQL databases and users, one database for each user?

I have a list of linux usernames, and I need to create a new postgres user for each linux username, and then an exclusive database for the new user in the home folder which no other users can see except the root.

I know how to use `CREATE DATABASE` but am not very familiar with loops etc. in PostgreSQL. Any pointers are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it from the shell, it will be a lot less work:

```
$ for user in $(cat usernames.txt); do 
   createuser -e $user
   createdb -e -O $user $user
done;
```

Incidentally, for random Postgres commands, you can use `psql -c` to run SQL from the command line non-interactively.

Answer (score 2):

One way is to make a shell script like db.sh

```
#!/bin/sh

users="foo bar baz"

for user in $users
do
  PGUSER=pguser createdb $user
done
```

Then do a

```
chmod 0755 db.sh
```

And execute it with

```
./db.sh
```

You may have to change PGUSER to your environment.

Shell loops:
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix/unix-loop-control.htm